# Codeigniter Cannot submit an ip adres on a form. Throws a Forbidden error

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

Here is my html form.

```
   <?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/subeler/add'), 'class="form-horizontal"');  ?> 
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="grup">Grup Adı</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="grup" required name="grup" value="<?php echo set_value('grup'); ?>" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="name">Şube Adı</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="name" required name="name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="ip">İp Adresi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="ip" required name="ip" value="<?php echo set_value("ip"); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="path">Database Adı</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="path" required name="path" value="<?php echo set_value('path'); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="lisans">Lisans Tarihi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="lisans" required name="lisans" value="<?php echo set_value('lisans'); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="il">İl</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="il" name="il" value="<?php echo set_value('il'); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
            <label for="ilce">İlçe</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-line">
                    <input type="text" id="ilce" name="ilce" value="<?php echo set_value('ilce'); ?>"class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-5">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="EKLE" class="btn btn-success m-t-15 waves-effect">
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

When I enter an ip adres to the input field like (http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xx/) redirect me to the 403 Forbidden page but when I put " (like "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:xx") to the ip adres it work fine. I tried to disable xss-filter disable in config files but result is same. Can anyone give some advice. How to submit an ip adres correctly with Codeigniter?

Server-Side

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->input->post("submit")) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('grup', 'Grup Adı', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Şube Adı', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ip', 'İp Adresi', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('path', 'Database Yolu', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lisans', 'Lisans Tarihi', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'marka' => $this->input->post('grup'),
                'ip' => $this->input->post('ip'),
                'il' => $this->input->post('il'),
                'ilce' => $this->input->post('ilce'),
                'databasePath' => $this->input->post('path'),
                'lisanse_date'=>$this->input->post('lisans')
            );
            $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
            $result = $this->sube_model->add_sube($data);
            if ($result) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Şube başarılı bir şekilde eklendi!');
                redirect(base_url('admin/subeler'));
            }
        } else {
            $data['view'] = 'admin/subeler/sube_ekle';
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);
        }
    } else {
        $data['view'] = 'admin/subeler/sube_ekle';
        $this->load->view('layout', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also add the Controller's code where the request is handled and validated.

Comment: Server-side added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not test the code exactly as provided as I don't make use of CodeIgniter 3 anymore, so I translated it into CodeIgniter 4.
Also, I could not test what `$this->sube_model->add_sube` does.

This, plus the form view you provided is working when setting `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx` on every form field.

You should trace when the 403 forbidden is triggered.
If you make use of [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) i'd recommend you to trace step by step where the execution fails.
Otherwise I'd just start removing code to find out at which point of the execution the exception is occurring.
If you are making use of a shared hosting, there could be any rule in the http server that is blocking the request, if that's the case, run it locally using a WAMP/LAMP bundle.

```php
    // CodeIgniter 4 approach
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
            $validation->setRule('grup', 'Grup Adı', 'trim|required');
            $validation->setRule('name', 'Şube Adı', 'trim|required');
            $validation->setRule('ip', 'İp Adresi', 'trim|required');
            $validation->setRule('path', 'Database Yolu', 'trim|required');
            $validation->setRule('lisans', 'Lisans Tarihi', 'trim|required');
            if ($validation->withRequest($this->request)->run() == true) {
                $data = array(
                    'name' => $this->request->getPost('name'),
                    'marka' => $this->request->getPost('grup'),
                    'ip' => $this->request->getPost('ip'),
                    'il' => $this->request->getPost('il'),
                    'ilce' => $this->request->getPost('ilce'),
                    'databasePath' => $this->request->getPost('path'),
                    'lisanse_date'=>$this->request->getPost('lisans')
                );
                // $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
                $result = $this->sube_model->add_sube($data);
                $result = 1;
                if ($result) {
                    session()->setFlashdata('msg', 'Şube başarılı bir şekilde eklendi!');
                    return redirect(base_url('admin/subeler'));
                }
            } else {
                $data['view'] = 'admin/subeler/sube_ekle';
                return view('layout', $data);
            }
        } else {
            $data['view'] = 'admin/subeler/sube_ekle';
            return view('layout', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help @savioret When i comment all the code in server side it redirect me the same forbidden page. So it is not related to server side code. I am hosting on dedicated server. Could it be related to htaccess file? I will tet with XDebug and write the result.

Comment: It could be related with _.htaccess_ however it's more likely that the hosting provider is blocking the _POST_ content from Apache (or whatever server it uses) configuration. Explain the problem to your provider. Another solution is that you [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) the value from javascript before the submit that way may not be blocked.